# react native - absolute import with alias name in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, es6-modules

I saw some projects using `import '@someDir/something'`, which solves the relative import evil.

Then I found this [blog post](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1) talking about this method. It basically tells you to create `package.json` in directories and specify their alias names.

I implemented it in my react-native project, which is based on expo, and it works well.

Something like this:

```
{"name": "@someDir"}
```

inside `src/someDir/package.json`.

And I can `import '@someDir/something'` everywhere.

**Why is this working? Where is the magic happening behind? Webpack or babel or react-native itself?**

I saw [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/741) discussing about this feature but I don't know where is it implemented.

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
              "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
      }
    }
}
```

It digged into the babel dependecies but cannot find anything related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be part of metro, the javascript bundler for react native.

https://www.belighted.com/blog/react-and-react-native-directories-management

https://facebook.github.io/metro